# Select specific records between two dateranges

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get unreserved hotel rooms according to a daterange which is given by user.

I have two tables

- **rooms** with columns room_id, roomno
- **reservations** with columns reserv_id, room_id, checkindate, checkoutdate

Im applying this query

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT roomno 
FROM rooms 
LEFT JOIN reservation ON rooms.room_id = reservation.room_id 
AND 
(
    (
        (reservation.checkindate > '$newreservcheckin') 
        AND
        (reservation.checkindate > '$newreservcheckout')
    ) 
    OR 
    (
        (reservation.checkoutdate < '$newreservcheckin') 
        AND 
        (reservation.checkoutdate < '$newreservcheckout')
    )
)";
```

**$newreservcheckin** and **$newreservcheckout** are date ranges provided by user

Let's say we have rooms with roomno as 100 and 101
now 100 is booked from 9-16-2016 to 9-18-2016 
and 100 is also booked from 9-27-2016 to 9-29-2016
and room 101 is unreserved(meaning it has no record in reservation table)

Suppose if user gives dates 9-26-2016 to 9-30-2016 query will ignore the room no 100 entry which is from 9-27-2016 to 9-29-2016 but will show the room no 100 with dates from 9-16-2016 to 9-18-2016 and will show 101 room

How to mold the query so that it may not give the same room but the one with different dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the rooms which are either (A) Not booked or (B) Booked but outside the range you are querying for, below query should work:

```
select no from room r
where not exists (
  select id from reservation where room_id = r.id)

union

select no from room r
where r.id not in (
  select distinct room_id from reservation
  where 
        checkindate between '2016-09-20' and '2016-09-22'
    OR 
        checkoutdate between '2016-09-20' and '2016-09-22'
)
```

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dced/6/0).

Answer (score 0):

You can join every reservation that overlaps with new checking dates and select those rooms which have nothing to join. In my query I expect that new guests can checkin at the same date when previous would checkout. If not - change "<" to "<=" and ">" to ">=".

```
SELECT 
    r.roomno
FROM
    rooms r
        LEFT JOIN
    reservations res ON res.room_id = r.room_id
        AND res.checkindate < '$newreservcheckout'
        AND res.checkoutdate > '$newreservcheckin'
WHERE res.reserv_id IS NULL
```